# Git post-receive auto-building

Tags: git, shell, githooks

I'd line to install a post-receive hook in a git repository to build and install the module to some custom testing area. The idea is that the testing area will always reflect the most current code in the repo.

The hook will:

1. clone/pull the code to tmp space
2. build the module
3. install the module to the testing area

Developers connect to the repo through SSH via gitosis. Is there any way to let the user disconnect after the data has been pushed so they don't need to stick around for the build?

I've tried something like this:

```
install(){
    unset GIT_DIR

    BARE_PATH=$PWD
    REPO_BASENAME=$(basename "$BARE_PATH")
    REPO_BASENAME=${BARE_PATH%.git}

    cd /my/scratch/space/

    if [ ! -d $REPOSITORY_BASENAME ] ; then
        git clone file://$BARE_PATH
    fi
    cd $REPO_BASENAME

   git pull
   ./install.sh

}

install &
```

This doesn't quite do it. In the above hook, it doesn't exit until after `install` finishes. Is there any way to let the hook exit before the install is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration , e.g. Jenkins.

Comment: They should have tough me about this one at school :)